# Why is the Scala-written lines deduplication app of mine so slow?

Tags: performance, scala

I've got some big (let's say 200 MiB - 2 GiB) textual files filled with tons of duplicated records. Each line can have about 100 or even more exact duplicates spread over the file. The task is to remove all the repetitions, leaving one unique instance of every record.

I've implemented it as follows:

```
object CleanFile {
  def apply(s: String, t: String) {
    import java.io.{PrintWriter, FileWriter, BufferedReader, FileReader}

    println("Reading " + s + "...")

    var linesRead = 0

    val lines = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()

    val fr = new FileReader(s)
    val br = new BufferedReader(fr)

    var rl = ""

    while (rl != null) {
      rl = br.readLine()

      if (!lines.contains(rl))
        lines += rl

      linesRead += 1

      if (linesRead > 0 && linesRead % 100000 == 0)
        println(linesRead + " lines read, " + lines.length + " unique found.")
    }

    br.close()
    fr.close()

    println(linesRead + " lines read, " + lines.length + " unique found.")
    println("Writing " + t + "...")

    val fw = new FileWriter(t);
    val pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    lines.foreach(line => pw.println(line))

    pw.close()
    fw.close()
  }
}
```

And it takes ~15 minutes (on my Core 2 Duo with 4 GB RAM) to process a 92 MiB file. While the following command:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

Takes about a minute to process 1.1 GiB file (which would take many hours with the above code of mine).

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try using a hash instead of that ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is wrong is that you're using an array to store the lines. Lookup (`lines.contains`) takes O(*n*) in an array, so the whole thing runs in O(*n*²) time. By contrast, the Awk solution uses a hashtable, meaning O(1) lookup and a total running time of O(*n*).

Try using a [`mutable.HashSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/HashSet.html) instead.

Comment: Indeed, HashSet does it much faster, close to the awk result. But it destroys the sequence order (which is tolerable but undesired in my case). Awk manages to preserve the order and still does a somewhat faster.

Comment: @Ivan: you can keep the order by emulating the Awk program more closely; if the line is not seen in the hash table, emit it immediately and add it, else just ignore it.

Comment: LinkedHashSets preserve insertion order http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: By the way, @larsmans, could you point to what to read to understand the issue? I have been always thinking that a hashtable is a key-value dictionary - the same as an array but accessed by a key instead of a simple numeric index and that it doesn't make sense to use when we need no association functionality.

Comment: @Ivan: look up hash tables in any book/resource on data structures, then ignore the values. What you end up with is no longer an associative map, but a simple set of keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just read all lines and call `.distinct` on them. I don't know how `distinct` is implemented, but I'm betting it uses a `HashSet` to do it.